# eeepc 701 linux virtualbox image

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, eee-pc

Any idea where i can download virtualbox vdi with eeepc's linux so i could test some configuration ideas in virtual machine on other computer before i apply them to real machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the ISO images for the EEEpc are on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eeecommunity/files/).

Comment: will it work if i'll just boot vm with that iso?

Comment: No idea, I just cloned an actual EEEpc with P2V software to run it! give me 5 minutes and I will test it for you.

Comment: 20 minutes! internet is a little slow this morning... downloading 1.0.4.19 iso from that site

Comment: Right, they offer a VmWare config file from their site, but I don't have time to mess around. I made a new VM and chose IDE hard drive and it worked fine! the ISO is self booting and installs fine, you may just have to mess around with a few settings.